# Summing Data in data frame in distinct categories

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy, dataframe

[image]

I have created an excel spreadsheet with data, and have transferred into a CSV file. I would like to add the data per ethnicity at each distinct year. I have tried to create a data index and have tried to total sum for each ethnicity but have been able to hold or contain the data. 
I have used df. as well as created 'for' loops so that I can hold the data per ethnicity but have received error messages. The original excel sheet contains the data frame per ethnicity for a specific show that is in relation to a specific year. I am unable to sum columns per year per ethnicity.

Should I use a for or if loop to step through specific years, is my approach to the correct process?

```
#this is the first method I have tried
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
# df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/allTheaterDataV2.csv')

import io
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['allTheaterDataV2.csv']))
# Daset is now stored in a Pandas Dataframe

#create list that contains the specific season that we want to reference
# print(df)

data = pd.DataFrame(allTheaterDataV2)

dataindex = [20082009, 20102011, 20112012, 20122013, 20132014, 20142015]
print(dataindex)


df.loc['total',:] = df.sum(axis=0)

print(df.loc[1:42, ['ASIAM','AFRAM','LAT','CAU','OTH']].sum())

# The second method I have tried is included below
for i in dataindex:
  # create a new data frame that stores the data per year
  hold_ASIAM = df[df.index == i]
  # allows for data for each season to be contained together
  ETHtotalASIAM = df['ASIAM'].sum()
  hold_ASIAM.append(ETHtotalASIAM)
print(hold_ASIAM)
```

I expect the output to give me the total(some #) per ethnicity (ex:AFRAM) per year (20082009), but the actual output is "name 'allTheaterDataV2' is not defined'

Comment: what is the full traceback? It looks like you never defined the variable `allTheaterDataV2` before calling it here `data = pd.DataFrame(allTheaterDataV2)`

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: how can i define the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['Billy Elliot','next to normal','shrek','guys and dolls',
                         'west side story', 'pal joey'],
                   'Season' : [20082009,20082009,20082009,
                               20082009,20082009,20082009],
                   'AFRAM' : [2,0,4,4,0,1],
                   'ASIAM' : [0,0,1,0,0,0],
                   'CAU' : [48,10,25,24,28,20],
                   'LAT' : [1,0,1,3,18,0],
                   'OTH' : [0,0,0,0,0,0]}) 

print(df)
#    AFRAM  ASIAM  CAU               ID  LAT  OTH    Season
# 0      2      0   48     Billy Elliot    1    0  20082009
# 1      0      0   10   next to normal    0    0  20082009
# 2      4      1   25            shrek    1    0  20082009
# 3      4      0   24   guys and dolls    3    0  20082009
# 4      0      0   28  west side story   18    0  20082009
# 5      1      0   20         pal joey    0    0  20082009

# drop the ID column since it is just a string
df = df.drop(['ID'], axis = 1)

# group by season and add the other columns
df = df.groupby('Season').sum()

print(df)
#             AFRAM  ASIAM  CAU  LAT  OTH
# Season                                 
# 20082009     11      1  155   23    0
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful but I'm not sure why but I am getting the TypeError: 'int' object is unsliceable.

Comment: It sounds like you need to convert the `df['Season']` column to a `string` then to `datetime`. Try adding `df['Season'] = df['Season'].astype(str)` before `df['Season'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Season'], format = '%Y%d%m')`. I also adjusted the answer to reflect my current comment.

Comment: Thanks, but I am still am unable to get the print(df) and instead getting a valueerror: unconverted data remain: 3. I have searched stack overflow but I am unable to figure out what this means. For context, I also have other data in the csv file other than ethnicity. Do I have to drop this data as well?

Comment: So the issue is i mistook your season data as being formatted YYYYDDMM but it is actually YYYY to YYYY combined to YYYY_YYYY. See what is hopefully my last edit to my previous answer that should work.