# Selecting Specific Data to Sum and Plot

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

[this is some of the data that is located in the excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBNft.jpg)

I want to select musical theater shows (known in the code as 'ID') that had more minorities than Caucasians in the cast
once determined, I wanted to place the information of the code selected shows into a new data frame that 
will only hold the shows, becasue it will be easier to manipulate. In the new data frame, I want to have in the same row for the show the related ethnicity, so I can compare to audience ethnicity. I then tried to plot this information.

So generally, I want to add up the values in specific rows if that row fits specific summation criteria. All data used in this project is located in an excel sheet that is converted to a csv and uploaded as a data frame. I would like to then plot the values of the cast in its entirety and compare the cast's ethnicity to the audience ethnicity.

I am working with python and I have tried to remove data that is not needed by selecting the columns by using an if statements so that the data frame only includes the shows that have more minorities than Caucasians, I then tried to use this information in the plot. I am unsure if I, have to filter all the unneeded columns if I am not using them in the calculations

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
#first need to import numpy so that calculations can be made

from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
# df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/allTheaterDataV2.csv')

import io
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['allTheaterDataV2.csv']))
# need to download excel sheet as csv and then upload into colab so that it can
# be manipulated as a dataframe 

# want to select shows(ID) that had more minorities than Caucasians in the cast
# once determined, the selected shows should be placed into a new data frame that 
# will only hold the shows and the related ethnicity, and compared to audience ethnicity
# this information should then be plotted 

# first we will determine the shows that have a majority ethnic cast

minorcal = list(df)
minorcal.remove('CAU')
minoritycastSUM = df[minorcal].sum(axis=1)

# print(minorcal)

# next, we determine how many people in the cast were Caucasian, so remove all others

caucasiancal = list(df)
# i first wanted to do caucasiancal.remove('AFRAM', 'ASIAM', 'LAT', 'OTH')
# but got the statement I could only have 1 argument so i just put each on their own line
caucasiancal.remove('AFRAM')
caucasiancal.remove('ASIAM')
caucasiancal.remove('LAT')
caucasiancal.remove('OTH')
idrowcaucal = df[caucasiancal].sum(axis=1)

minoritycompare = old.filter(['idrowcaucal','minoritycastSUM'])
print(minoritycompare)

# now compare the two values per line
if minoritycastSUM < caucasiancal:
  minoritydf = pd.df.minorcal.append()
  # plot new data frame per each show and compare to audience ethnicity
  df.plot(x=['AFRAM', 'ASIAM', 'CAU', 'LAT', 'OTH', 'WHT', 'BLK', 'ASN', 'HSP', 'MRO'], y = [''])
             # i am unsure how to call the specific value for each column
  plt.title('ID Ethnicity Comparison')
             # i am unsure how to call the specific show so that only one show is per plot so for now i just subbed in 'ID' 
  plt.xlabel('Ethnicity comparison')
  plt.ylabel('Number of Cast Members/Audience Members')
  plt.show()
```

I would like to see the data frame with specific shows that fit within the criteria, and then the plot for the show, but right now I am getting errors on how to formulate the new data frame and python saying that the lengths of the if statements cannot be used.[2]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this will *not be a complete answer*, as

1. I don't know how you're imagining your final plot to look like
2. I don't know what the columns in your DataFrame are (consider using more descriptive column labels, e.g. 'caucasian actors' instead of 'CAU',…)
3. it is unclear to me whether any trend can be formed from your data, since the screenshot you've posted shows equal audience compositions for the first movies

Nevertheless, I built upon the DataFrame in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55988558/565489), and maybe this initial plot of "non caucasian/caucasian ratio" per movie can point you in the right direction.
Perhaps you could build a similar set of sum & ratio columns for the audience columns, and then plot the actor ratio as a function of the audience ratio to see whether a more caucasian audience prefers more or less caucasian actors (*I guess that's what you're after?*).

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['Billy Elliot','next to normal','shrek','guys and dolls',
                         'west side story', 'pal joey'],
                   'Season' : [20082009,20082009,20082009,
                               20082009,20082009,20082009],
                   'AFRAM' : [2,0,4,4,0,1],
                   'ASIAM' : [0,0,1,0,0,0],
                   'CAU' : [48,10,25,24,28,20],
                   'LAT' : [1,0,1,3,18,0],
                   'OTH' : [0,0,0,0,0,0],
                   'WHT' : [73.7,73.7,73.7,73.7,73.7,73.7]}) 

## define a sum column for non caucasian actors (I suppose?)
df['non_cau']=df[['AFRAM','ASIAM','LAT','OTH']].sum(axis=1)
## build a ratio of non caucasian to caucasian
df['cau_ratio']=df['non_cau']/df['CAU']

## make a quick plot
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(df['ID'],df['cau_ratio'])
ax.set_ylabel('non cau / cau ratio')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: THANK YOU!! I edited the question to include a better description, but this was great. Follow up question, how can I make the plot bigger? I have tried multiple ways with no success.

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation, but what I wanted was your calculations (thanks) and ['WHT', 'BLK', 'ASN', 'HSP', 'MRO'] on the same axis(cast vs audience). The reason this has been difficult is becasue I do not want to add all the columns (that's why I dropped the unneeded columns so that I could only add in needed columns).

Comment: @tnndynamite to [change the figure size](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html#matplotlib.pyplot.figure), use the `figsize` parameter, e.g. `fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))`. Note that you can easily drop rows (i.e. shows) that are below a certain "non caucasian"-threshold e.g. via `df=df[(df['cau_ratio']>=0.2)]`